# Creating an figure by means of: 'import matplot lib as mpl ' and 'self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=dpi, figsize=(2, 2))'

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, figure

I have already used this sintax 'self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=dpi, figsize=(2, 2))' for create figures in the folllowing conditions : Python - 3.8.6 and  Matplotlib - 3.4.1, and it worked fine.

Now I have to use Matplotlib - 3.7.3, and in doing so I receive the red message "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'figure' ". But in fact this sintax exists in docs of this version of Matplotlib.

Is there any equivalent or newer function(s) set to substitute that line?

Thank you

That sintax was working fine for creating figures, I expected that in new Matplotlib version worked as well.

Comment: the correct way is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `fig = plt.figure()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access *figure()* from Matplotlib, then this will fail as such a function does not exist in Matplotlib's *home* directory. You need to go to the subdirectory *pyplot* in order to access figure() from Matplotlib. So, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then you can do:

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

Remember that Matplotlib.pyplot.figure() can work with mpl_toolkits.

The bottom line is that you can't access figure() from Matplotlib's home directory; you need to get to one of its subdirectories to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Figure should not be a problem, you need to explicitely import it from matplotlib.figure, though.

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>>> mpl.__version__
'3.8.2'
```

You are right *not* to use the pyplot / plt interface. That one is for interactive use, not for integration into an application.

For integration with wx you should stay with the object oriented interface.

See here for integration examples:

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/main/galleries/examples/user_interfaces
- https://github.com/wxGlade/wxGlade/tree/master/examples